# moved on, out or in

Tags: prepositions

> Our friendship grew from working on the same team to having lunch when we had both moved (on - out - in), then to seeing each other outside work.

Please, tell me which one is the correct answer because it made me really confused.

Comment: _Moved in_: started living or working in a particular place. _Moved out_: stopped living or working in a particular place. _Moved on_: changed to a new something - a home, or a job, or a relationship, or a stage of any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Initially they were just colleagues:

> Our friendship grew from working on the same team

Then they changed jobs:

> to having lunch when we had both **[moved on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/move%20on)**

(See 3rd example.)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's supposed to be "moved in" because the context implies they started living together.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense, I would expect them to seeing each other regularly and deliberately and only then moving in together. Plus I see absolutely nothing that implies cohabitation.

Comment: Indeed. If the friendship only later developed to 'seeing each other outside work', they were obviously not living together.